# why it's throwing error while building the project in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am developing an application on Angular 6 & it's working fine on my local development environment but when I am trying to build my Angular using `ng build --prod` 6 app it's throwing error.
[image: Error details]

Home.Component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  src: HTMLImageElement; 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Home.component.html

```
<section class="featured-lis">
    <div class="container padding_zero">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="jumbotron custom_ads">
                    <img [src]="src/assets/images/ads/ad1.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-cta">
                    <div class="cta-icon">
                        <i class="lni-grid"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Refreshing Design</h4>
                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-cta">
                    <div class="cta-icon">
                        <i class="lni-brush"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>Easy to Customize</h4>
                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="single-cta">
                    <div class="cta-icon">
                        <i class="lni-headphone-alt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>24/7 Support</h4>
                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: Provide code of your HomeComponent please

Comment: I have also tried by removing src: HTMLImageElement;

Comment: home.component.html - errors are in html file

Comment: and I have have defined img tags as:  [src]="assets/img/testimonial/img2.png"

Comment: first you are making image tag as a property to bind it then you are giving it a specific path here which is not acceptable.Do not make src as a property just write it simply as `src` and you'll see the src error will be removed. Now we need your html code here to further see what errors are you getting

Comment: ng build --prod usually throw these errors when there are properties that are not completely defined and are unused in the code. So either you can remove them or you can define them or just give them an initialization like `src: any` and thats it

Answer (score 0):

Such error can occure if you trying accessing properties of the class which were not declared properly.

For example, if you have such component (syntax simplified):

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOninit() {}
}
```

And the in its component.html file you are trying to access some not declared properties, for example:

```
<div>{{ads}}</div>
```

It will not let you to build project correctly.

To fix that, please declare all properties you use in component class:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
        ads: any;
        src: any;
        assets: any;  // and other....

        constructor() {}

        ngOninit() {}
        ... further code of your component
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<img [src]="src/assets/images/ads/ad1.png" alt="">
```

to

```
<img [src]="'src/assets/images/ads/ad1.png'" alt="">
```

or even

```
<img src="src/assets/images/ads/ad1.png" alt="">
```

And every similar issues.